# What are common culprits for TMP slowness

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, template-meta-programming

I have a project which uses quite a bit of C++ template meta-programming. This makes compile times long. I understand that I cannot have the cake and eat it too but I would like to know some tips and tricks on how to reduce compile times. I have already tried explicit instantiations and while that might help in some cases, a lot of the times, the instances are unique to a particular compilation unit in which case explicit instantiation does nothing to help. And now we're only talking about Clang which does a pretty good job. When I try this on G++, the compile time just explodes. For one file, I gave up waiting for it to compile after 45 minutes.

- Are there any common culprits when it comes to template meta-programming, things that are known to often be problematic? What techniques should I avoid and what should I do instead?
- Are there any areas where GCC is known to perform worse than Clang and is there any way to work around this?

I'm using mostly plain vanilla C++11 techniques, I don't use Boost MPL or similar libraries.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some advises regarding metaprogramming with C++11 and beyond:

- **Prefer variadic expansion based algorithms**. Variadic templates are usually handled quickly by the compiler compared to the O(n) chain of template instantiations one usually need for typelists and related on old C++98/03. I'm eager to see C++1z fold expressions, as a way to implement `fold` family metafuntcitons using pack expansion.
- **Avoid inheritance chains**: Algorithms based on recursive inheritance usually perform badly since the compiler should track the inheritance tree metadata. Prefer raw calls to next `::type` instead of inheriting directly from the next "call" as a shorthand to get that `type` member.
- **Prefer inheritance pack expansion to recursive inheritance**: That is, if you are implementing a tuple like thing, prefer

  ```
  template<typename... Ts>
  struct tuple : Ts...
  ```

  to

  ```
  template<typename Head, typename... Tail>
  struct tuple : Head, tuple<Tail...>
  ```

  since the compiler should intantiate N subtypes on the latter, plus the inheritance overhead described at point above.
- **Prefer name lookup based algorithms**: Name lookup usually performs faster than recursive template instantiation. So, consider doing something like `decltype(declval<T>().f())` to compute a type, where the result is in the correct f overload.

Comment: Unfortunately, these are things I already do. Some things that I found really increased compile times was my use of `std::make_shared` and `std::shared_ptr`. I replaced these with my own reference counting using `std::atomic` since I was doing type erasure anyway.

Comment: @EmilEriksson It's possible to still use `std::shared_ptr` and not get too much extra overhead http://blog2.emptycrate.com/content/template-code-bloat-revisited-smaller-makeshared

Comment: In this case, even if I reduced the number of `std::shared_ptr` instantiations, I would still have too many of them and `std::shared_ptr` is more expensive to instantiate than my own implementation. Of course, it is expensive for a good reason, that flexibility is required for a standard library class that is going to be used everywhere. But I have a very specific use case and thus, I was able to reduce compile times by using another solution.

Answer (score 0):

In our projects we just used thinking and trials. I.e. first we think "what are the complex templates here" and then we tried to isolate these templates or remove them or refactor to see if compile time changes. Often templates compile time is accompanied by increased memory usage, I even reported a gcc bug once on that matter (https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54056).

There's another trick that helped several times, using the -Q command-line switch (show functions that gcc currently compiles). E.g. for the bug linked above it was clear that gcc slowed down on those buggy templates.